# Book series, girl who works for a supernatural forces unit?

Tags: story-identification, powers

I am looking for a book series I read approximately 6 years ago (2010), in which a girl works for a special supernatural forces unit. They take down zombies, vampires, werewolves, etc.. She lives there and her best friend is a mermaid and I think her ex-boyfriend is a fairie. I really want to read this book again but I cannot think of the name! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[*Paranormalcy*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paranormalcy) (2010)

[image: Book cover]

> Paranormalcy follows the efforts of the International Paranormal Containment Agency (IPCA), a group tasked with policing various mythological beings who live secretly among humans. The protagonist of the story is an IPCA officer named Evie, a teenage girl who possesses an ability to detect paranormals disguised as human beings.
>
> Evie's allies include a shape-shifting boy named Lend, who she meets as the story begins, and a faerie named Reth, whom she previously admired. Both young men become romantic interests of Evie's as the tale progresses, while the three of them are joined by other companions as well. At its center, Paranormalcy examines Evie's attempts to balance her IPCA duties with her growing desire to lead a normal teenage life.

It was followed by *Supernaturally* (2011) where Evie flirts with a normal life and learns more about her background and *Endlessly* (2012), which according to Wikipedia, "Evie must deal with a new IPCA director, as well as the continuing battle against the Dark Faerie Queen."

Comment: @katelynrnyletak: When you return, if could click the checkmark under the voting buttons if this answered your question, I'd be much obliged.